# Oracle randomly shuffling entire rows

Tags: sql, arrays, oracle, shuffle

have a locations table that contains 3 types of records (see below). I only need  to SELECT record_type = 'G' rows.

I want to wrap the data in a loop ( ie 5 times) but how can I randomly shuffle the ENTIRE rows, by location_id, so they appear in a different order with each iteration of the loop? Perhaps, sticking the rows into an array and shuffling the array?

Note, I don't want to shuffle the columns, I want the row kept in tact. In the future more locations maybe added.

```
CREATE TABLE locations AS
SELECT level AS location_id,
       'Door ' || level AS location_name,

CASE round(dbms_random.value(1,3)) 
            WHEN 1 THEN 'A' 
            WHEN 2 THEN 'T' 
            WHEN 3 THEN 'G' 
         END AS location_type

FROM   dual
CONNECT BY level <= 25;

SELECT * from tour_detail 
Order by tour_id, tour_time

TOUR_ID TOUR_TIME    LOCATION_ID
1   06212020 00:10:25   2
1   06212020 00:21:05   18
1   06212020 00:30:33   11
1   06212020 00:40:51   17
1   06212020 00:52:13   4
1   06212020 01:01:42   2
1   06212020 01:07:52   11
```

We have an access control system when you slide your card it records card_num, location_id, access_date in MMDDYYY HH24:MI:SS format.

Some wanted to create a guard tour system. That compares the access_date to the tour_detail detail date. If within a certain criteria say + or - 2 minutes that means the guard was on time, if GT  or LT 2 minutes we log an early or late, if GT Or LT 5 minutes or no access_history record we log a no show.

I was asked to throw together some testing data. As you can see the tour_detail records contain MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS so I'm thinking about changing the tour_detail records to interval hour to minute but I have little experience working with that.

Comment: "randomly shuffle" and "in a different order with each iteration of the loop" are not achievable at the same time. With a random shuffle, you can get the same order twice or more. Do you want to iterate through every possible order combination, once? Or do you just want a random ordering every time?

Comment: No I want to just shuffle it don't need every combination different. I want this How could do this:

BEGIN
  FOR l_counter IN 1..5
  LOOP
    For 1 to every location.count
    Loop
       Print location_id 
    End loop
   Randomly shuffle all records in locations table
  END LOOP;
END;

Answer (score 1):

> so they appear in a different order with each iteration of the loop

This is pointless. You are inserting rows into a table. Rows (in a RDBMS table) aren't **stored** in any particular order.

But, you can sort them when selecting from that table and - in order to do that - you have to use the `order by` clause.

---

As of selecting, see if this helps:

```
SQL> with data as
  2    (select empno, ename, job, sal
  3     from emp
  4     where deptno = 20
  5     order by round(dbms_random.value(0, 15))
  6    )
  7  select column_value, d.*
  8  from data d cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  9                                             connect by level <= 5
 10                                            ) as sys.odcinumberlist));

COLUMN_VALUE      EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
------------ ---------- ---------- --------- ----------
           4       7902 FORD       ANALYST         3000
           4       7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         3000
           2       7369 SMITH      CLERK           1000
           4       7369 SMITH      CLERK           1000
           1       7369 SMITH      CLERK           1000
           5       7566 JONES      MANAGER         2975
           1       7876 ADAMS      CLERK           1100
           1       7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         3000
           5       7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         3000
           3       7876 ADAMS      CLERK           1100
           1       7902 FORD       ANALYST         3000
           2       7876 ADAMS      CLERK           1100
           5       7902 FORD       ANALYST         3000
           3       7902 FORD       ANALYST         3000
           3       7566 JONES      MANAGER         2975
           1       7566 JONES      MANAGER         2975
           3       7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         3000
           2       7902 FORD       ANALYST         3000
           4       7566 JONES      MANAGER         2975
           5       7876 ADAMS      CLERK           1100
           2       7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         3000
           3       7369 SMITH      CLERK           1000
           4       7876 ADAMS      CLERK           1100
           2       7566 JONES      MANAGER         2975
           5       7369 SMITH      CLERK           1000

25 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: I want to do this

BEGIN
  FOR l_counter IN 1..5
  LOOP
    For 1 to every location.count
    Loop
       Print location_id 
    End loop
   Randomly shuffle all records in locations table
  END LOOP;
END;

Comment: I edited my answer and added an example; have a look, please.

Comment: It helps a lot. Just a couple of questions. Where is column_value coming from? Can I add a column outside of the cte like sysdate+random.value. lastly can can I have a table called t1 and add that to the cte as my goal is to generate data from 2 different tables and a sysdate value and INSERT them into a new table. Thanks for patience and expertise. For some I am better with PLSQL than Sql

Comment: You're welcome. COLUMN_VALUE is coming from the TABLE function; if it weren't for it, you'd use LEVEL (and get many duplicate rows). As of your other questions: I'd say "yes, you can do that"; your best option is to actually **try it** and see what happens.

Comment: Also, I've seen that you asked many questions and never accepted any answer you got. Why? Do you know that you discourage future answers to your questions that way? People don't know whether effort they put into helping you actually *helps*.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to offend anyone. I see people mark their responses answered I thought that was it. In addition, I only see a share, edit, comment  and flag button. I don't see an accepted button. If you tell me where it is I'm more than happy to follow the rules of the forum. Again my apologies

Comment: No problem, just saying. As of "What should I do when someone answers my question", read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a table with 5 `ID`s

```
create table tab as
select rownum id from dual connect by level <= 5;
```

THis produce a random order output *of the rows*

```
select * from tab order by dbms_random.value;

        ID
----------
         2
         4
         5
         1
         3
```

If you repeat the statment you get a different (random) result

```
        ID
----------
         5
         4
         2
         1
         3
```

So simple repaet the query in the loop or make something like this

```
with data as (
select 1 pass_id, id  from tab  
union all
select 2 pass_id, id  from tab  
union all
select 3 pass_id, id  from tab )
select * from data
order by 1,dbms_random.value
```

Comment: I want to do this:

BEGIN
  FOR l_counter IN 1..5
  LOOP
    For 1 to every location.count
    Loop
       Print location_id 
    End loop
   Randomly shuffle all records in locations table
  END LOOP;
END;

Comment: @Beefstu provide the expected output with a small data (say 5 `location_id`) - sorry it is still not clear enough for my what you want to *shuffle* out.

Comment: @Beefstu - why are you so wedded to using a for-loop? That solution uses a cursor, in which --- _by definition_ --- the rows are already 'ordered' before you ever get them.  What's wrong with using the simple sql presented by others?  If you need to do some cursor-loop processing on the rows, returned in a random order, then you would need an explicit cursor based on one of those sql solutions.  But I strongly sustpect we are really dealing with and 'x-y problem' here.

Comment: I'm not married to a for loop, it just seems like the easiest way to accomplish a task as I'm not a developer. Thanks for the advice. I'll look into cursors.

Comment: @bomber I edited original question with more details